# How should I create my app that can be update?

Tags: android, google-play

Imagine you have a storybook app created via android for children and it has a few story in version 1.
now you want the buyers that buy your app be able to get a story you have just wrote and published it on market.
Now my first question is: How should I build my app that the buyers can get just that story?
My second question is: what should I published in market?

Comment: Every app is updateable on the market by default. There are 2 things you can't change: package name, and the key used for publishing, so choose carefully.

Comment: You have to do nothing. Just keep the Signing key, same package name.

Answer (score 3):

In `AndroidManifext.xml` file change these parameters:

```
android:versionCode="x"
android:versionName="x.x"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add your new version apk to android market(Google Play), provided you sign the app with the same key and update the version in the manifest of your Application. It takes nothing more.

Consider this to be your manifest,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

For the next version change this to,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```